# General Approach to Working with Data in DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, concept

Question for experienced Pandas users on approach to working with Dataframe data.

Invariably we want to use Pandas to explore relationships among data elements. Sometimes we use groupby type functions to get summary level data on subsets of the data.  Sometimes we use plots and charts to compare one column of data against another.  I'm sure there are other application I haven't thought of.

When I speak with other fairly novice users like myself, they generally try to extract portions of a "large" dataframe into smaller dfs that are sorted or formatted properly to run applications or plot.  This approach certainly has disadvantages in that if you strip out a subset of data into a smaller df and then want to run an analysis against a column of data you left in the bigger df, you have to go back and recut stuff.

My question is - is best practices for more experienced users to leave the large dataframe and try to syntactically pull out the data in such a way that the effect is the same or similar to cutting out a smaller df?  Or is it best to actually cut out smaller dfs to work with?

Thanks in advance.